# How to query the historic state of items at a specific date?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to query the state of a work item at a specific date. E.g. I want to know what was the state of all work items of one team last Monday. Of course I can go through all single items and check the state graphs manually, but that's not really feasible with several hundred items.

I tried to use a combination of different fields, including the 'State Change Date' but it only tells me when a change happened but not what was the specific state on the selected date.

Is there any way to query the historical states of a work item?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. Yes the answer is helpful and I also accepted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to query the historic state of items at a specific date?

You can achieve this in Power Bi. First [create an Analytics view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/analytics-views-create?view=azure-devops#open-analytics-to-access-views) in Azure DevOps.
For example:

[image]

Then [open this analytics view in Power Bi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops).

[image]

Filter by **Date** field:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I was hoping to get this directly with a query in Azure DevOps. Nevertheless I will forward this to one of my Data Analysts. Thanks again!

Comment: I am afraid this is currently not possible in azure devops query. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site.